# Errors in installation & Update

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, software-updates

I have an installation of Kali VM on VirtualBox, I've always installed new programs without any problems, but I haven't been able for a few days. For example, here are the errors when I try to install Sublist3r:

[image]

So I tried the general update and this is the result:

[image]

I specify that I can ping everything, both google and 192.99.200.113 (the IP specified as non-reachable)
Has anyone some clue to resolve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: -> https://forums.kali.org/forumdisplay.php?13-Kali-Linux-TroubleShooting

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)